# simple authorisation / login capability in php

Tags: php, security, authentication

I'm looking to implement user login onto my site for the first time.  I'm happy to either build my own solution, or implement something open source, however no package has been an obvious choice in my search so far.  Equally, I'm fully aware that as an intermediate php programmer at best, I am highly likely to miss something obvious if I roll my own solution, and leave the doors well and truly open.

Any suggestions?  We're not talking super sensitive or payment data here, but equally, I'm keen not to have people mess up my site!

requirements are
- php based
- simple as possible, not need for fancy bells and whistles
- not Zend framework, since i've now rolled my own very basic frameworkthanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422250/php-framework-or-template-engine-or-something-else)

Thanks for your input.

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth which is both framework-agnostic and database-agnostic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few good security gotcha's are

- **never** store the an un-encrypted users password in the database
- **never** store the users password or even a hash of the password in session or cookie data.
- If you need to have ensure that the login is secure you have to use https.

I found these article very helpful in building login systems with cookies:

- [blog post on the fishbowl](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/).
- [Improved Persistent Login Cookie Best Practice](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice)

Comment: +1 Thank you, i was storing the password in a session variable unadvertedly

Comment: Why can't you store a password on a SESSION? I don't see how that's insecure.

Comment: I know it's old, but I will still leave my answer. You cannot leave password in session because in case of any javascript injection, someone can still this password and use it. Some hacker also can see the headers that were send to server, so it's easy to get this password. Also 99.999% of people is using this same username and password for multiple sites.

Answer (score 3):

"You'll put your eye out kid."

Security is hard. I hate to say this, but the odds of you making a simple authorization scheme that is secure are quite slim. There is no easy mode here. So you might want to start by reading through a bunch of authentication code in the various frameworks/cmses, and other places where you can see how others have done it, and begin researching.

Here are some links: 
http://www.topmost.se/personal/articles/casual-cryptography-for-web-developers.htm
http://pear.php.net/packages.php?catpid=1

Answer (score 0):

I find that for *some* uses, building my own using http authentication is sufficient. I'd recommend [this](https://www.php.net/features.http-auth) as a starting point.

Since you have your own basic framework, it should not be too difficult to include the authentication code in some place that is common.

Some advantages are

- Not a lot of code.
- Does not require
  cookies or URL rewriting.

Disadvantages

- Doesn't scale well to more granular
  access control.
- No *easy* way to "log
  out".

--
bmb

Answer (score -1):

This is not that hard, and fun to code, as a beginner.

You need a place to store your data (let's say a mysql database).

You should at least have a login field, and a password field. (the password should be stored crypter using sha1() for instance).

Now, you have to display a login form. I assume this is ok for you.

What is to be done, whenever we get the login and the password?

Query the database to see wether there is a match with login_base == login_form and password_base == sha1(password_form).

If yes, you set something, like a session for instance.

So on a page where one should be logged, you only have to check if there is a session set.

This is for the basis; then you can add some levels and so on.

Comment: -1 for the ridiculously incorrect statement "This is not that hard, and fun to code, as a beginner." There are a million ways to get basic auth wrong, and beginners code auth like lemmings jumping off a cliff.